# Run a function once in MutationObserver for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, flags, mutation-observers

I'm using MutationObserver to observe if any element with the class `last-move` changes its inline style. For example, it could look like this:
`<square class="last-move" style="transform: translate(204px, 68px);"></square>`
On the page, there are two squares with this `last-move` class, so I need to observe if any of them change. If either one or both of them change, I'd like to run the function `pieceMoved()`. This is the foundation I'm working with.

```
function observeNewMove() {
  const targetElements = document.querySelectorAll('.last-move');

  targetElements.forEach((targetElement) => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
      for (const mutation of mutationsList) { // For loop to see if any of the two elements have changed.
        if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'style') {
            pieceMoved(); // Function to be called once.
        }
      }
    });

    observer.observe(targetElement, { attributes: true });
  });
}
```

The problem becomes that `pieceMoved()` is called at least twice since the two squares with `last-move` class both change style most of the times, but I'd like for `pieceMoved()` to be called once, even if the for loop runs for two iterations.

To sum it up, I'd like for `pieceMoved()` to be run only once, even if the for loop iterates for more than that.

I've tried using different type of flag systems with both local and global variables, starting with false-true, then true-false, and everything in-between. Here's an example

```
function observeNewMove() {
  let flag = false;
  const targetElements = document.querySelectorAll('.last-move');

  targetElements.forEach((targetElement) => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
      for (const mutation of mutationsList) { // For loop to see if any of the two elements have changed.
        if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'style') {
            if (flag) {
                pieceMoved(); // Function to be called once.
            }
            flag = true;
        }
      }
    });

    observer.observe(targetElement, { attributes: true });
  });
}
```

This will work for the first time `observeNewMove()` is called, but not for subsequent moves (as `observeNewMove()` is not called again, it kind of runs forever until disconnected if I've understood it correctly). Changing the placement of  `let flag = false;` will either cause `pieceMoved()` to never be called (`flag = false` always, or called twice all the time (`flag = true` always).

Answer (score 0):

```
function observeNewMove() {
  const targetElements = document.querySelectorAll('.last-move');

  targetElements.forEach((targetElement) => {
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
      // declare it before loop
      let once = false
      for (const mutation of mutationsList) { // For loop to see if any of the two elements have changed.
        if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'style') {
            // change it in the loop
            once = true
        }
      }
      // check it after the loop
      if (once) {
        pieceMoved(); // Function to be called once.
      }
    });

    observer.observe(targetElement, { attributes: true });
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm sad to say that this approach does not work as `pieceMoved()` is still inside `targetElements.forEach((targetElement) => { ... }`. All code inside `if (once) { ... }` will be run twice.